# for loop in fish shell only goes a maximum of 3 times

Tags: fish

I'm using fish shell to do a simple for loop. For some reason it only iterates three times instead of a 100 (or whatever I put in there). What am I doing wrong?

```
error ➜  for i in seq 1 100
             echo hi
         end
hi
hi
hi
error ➜
```

Note that running `seq 1 100` will -as expected- output numbers from 1 to 100.

Here's my fish version:

```
error ➜  fish --version
fish, version 3.0.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're not launching the `seq` command.

You are doing this

```sh
for i in "seq" "1" "100"
```

when you want to do this

```sh
for i in (seq 1 100)
# .......^.........^  command substitution
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it right after posting. It seems I'm not a particularly smart person lol. Decided to leave it up for others though because it happened to me multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm so the answer to my question is very simple.

I should have `(seq 1 100)` instead of `seq 1 100`.

It needs to be enclosed in brackets to have the `seq` command evaluated. Instead, what I just gave fish is an array of three strings ("seq" "1" "100") who happened to look like a command lol.

So yeah I am not a very intelligent person.